# Add Empty/Blank Page to PdfDocument java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, pdfdocument

It is there any way to add a Blank Page to an existing PdfDocument ? I've created a method like this:

```
  public void addEmptyPage(PdfDocument pdfDocument){
    pdfDocument.addNewPage();
    pdfDocument.close();
}
```

However , when I use it with a PdfDocument , it throws :

```
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects.
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.makeIndirect(PdfObject.java:228) ~[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject.makeIndirect(PdfObject.java:248) ~[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.<init>(PdfPage.java:104) ~[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.addNewPage(PdfDocument.java:416) ~[kernel-7.1.1.jar:?]
```

Which is the correct way to insert a Blank page into a pdf document?

Comment: Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392082/add-blank-page-to-pdfdocument but why did you delete instead of edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects.

That exception indicates that you initialize your `PdfDocument` with only a `PdfReader`, no `PdfWriter`. You don't show your `PdfDocument` instantiation code but I assume you do something like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader);
```

Such documents are for *reading only*. (Actually you can do some minor manipulations but nothing as big as adding pages.)

If you want to *edit* a PDF, initialize your `PdfDocument` with both a `PdfReader` and a `PdfWriter`, e.g.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DESTINATION);
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
```

If you want to store the edited file at the same location as the original file,
you **must not** use the same file name as `SOURCE` in the `PdfReader` and as `DESTINATION` in the `PdfWriter`.

Either first write to a temporary file, close all participating objects, and then replace the original file with the temporary file:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("document.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("document-temp.pdf");
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
...
document.close();
Path filePath = Path.of("document.pdf");
Path tempPath = Path.of("document-temp.pdf");
Files.move(tempPath, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Or read the original file into a `byte[]` and initialize the `PdfReader` from that array:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("document.pdf"))));
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("document.pdf");
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
...
document.close();
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of your explanation please ? I'm not familiar with Pdfs in Java

Comment: I've added some code. I originally did not add it because it's mostly not specific to PDFs but basic Java stuff.

Comment: Can you check my new question about PDF ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58415525/cannot-copy-indirect-object-from-the-document-that-is-being-written-java